# Nginx and dynamic X-Forwarded-For blocklist

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I am running Nginx behind a proxy. I am getting visitors' real IP addresses through `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request header. I'd like to block individual IPs based on a dynamic block list, up to 10000+ IPs.

I was looking into ModSecurity to do this, but it looks too complex with very arcane and brittle configuration language just for doing IP blocking. What other alternatives there are?

Also, it is viable to generate Nginx rules configuration (`ip-blocklist.conf`) for the inclusion in the main Nginx config e.g. for every 5 minutes and then gracefully restart Nginx? How scaleable are Nginx rules e.g. up to 10k entries?

Comment: What are you trying to block? You may be better off doing something other than blocking within nginx.

Comment: I am blocking certain requests behind a proxy and in this case the requests cannot be blocked before the proxy.

Comment: Found this - have not yet tried whether it works a solution or not http://devblog.mixlr.com/2012/09/01/nginx-lua/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+NoFactZone+%28No+Fact+Zone+-+Stephen+Colbert+news+blog+and+fan+site%29

Comment: I don't know, since you still haven't explained what you are trying to do.